# Overwriting ZipEntrys

Tags: java, stream, zip, overwrite

Simple question,

I'm writing a series of text files into a zip, just wrapping a fileoutputstream in a zipoutputstream and then in a printwriter.

```
public static int saveData(File outfile, DataStructure input) {
//variables
ArrayList<String> out = null;
FileOutputStream fileout = null;
ZipOutputStream zipout = null;
PrintWriter printer = null;

//parameter tests

try {
    fileout = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
    zipout = new ZipOutputStream(fileout);
    printer = new PrintWriter(zipout);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return util.FILE_INVALID;
}

for(DataItem data : input){
    //process the data into a list of strings

    try {
    zipout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry( dataFileName ));
    for(String s : out) {
        printer.println(s);
    }
    zipout.closeEntry();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        fileout.close();
    } catch (Exception x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
        return util.CRITICAL_ERROR;
    }
    e.printStackTrace();
    return util.CRITICAL_ERROR;
    }

}


try {
    fileout.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return util.CRITICAL_ERROR;
}

return util.SUCCESS;

}
```

Previously in the app i've been developing I've just been saving to the current directory for testing and I know in the case of a file already existing that the file will be overwritten (and have been exploiting this).  What I dont know is the behaviour for zips.  Will it overwrite entries of the same name?  Or will it simply overwrite the whole zip file (which would be convenient for my purposes.

K.Barad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to add a duplicate ZipEntry you will get an exception. If you want to replace the current entry you need to delete it and re-insert it. I suspect the exception you get is much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790430/update-file-in-a-jar).

Comment: well for now I've been taking it safe and just manually checking for and deleting the file, before making it afresh (the zip is being used to group and compress 3-20 outputs from a program, keeping old ones not from this session would be deceptive).  in the case of delete and reinsert is there a way to remove an entry without unzipping and rezipping?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  It's a pity, but not a disaster.

Answer (score 4):

As Joel said, If you try to add a duplicate ZipEntry you will get an exception. If you want to replace the current entry you need to delete it and re-insert it.
You might want to do something like here below to achieve it:

```
    private ZipFile addFileToExistingZip(File zipFile, File versionFile) throws IOException{
    // get a temp file
    File tempFile = File.createTempFile(zipFile.getName(), null);
    // delete it, otherwise you cannot rename your existing zip to it.
    tempFile.delete();

    boolean renameOk=zipFile.renameTo(tempFile);
    if (!renameOk)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("could not rename the file "+zipFile.getAbsolutePath()+" to "+tempFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096 * 1024];

    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));

    ZipEntry entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    while (entry != null) {
        String name = entry.getName();
        boolean toBeDeleted = false;
            if (versionFile.getName().indexOf(name) != -1) {
                toBeDeleted = true;
            }
        if(!toBeDeleted){
            // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
            // Transfer bytes from the ZIP file to the output file
            int len;
            while ((len = zin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
        entry = zin.getNextEntry();
    }
    // Close the streams
    zin.close();
    // Compress the files
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(versionFile);
    String fName = versionFile.getName();
    // Add ZIP entry to output stream.
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fName));
    // Transfer bytes from the file to the ZIP file
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    // Complete the entry
    out.closeEntry();
    in.close();
    // Complete the ZIP file
    out.close();
    tempFile.delete();

    return new ZipFile(zipFile);
}
```

The above code worked for me where the need was to add a new zip entry to an existing zip file. If the entry is already present inside the zip, then overwrite it.
Comments/improvements in the code are welcome!
Thanks!